# How can I change the title heading shown in Auth0 Lock?

Tags: angular, auth0

I want to change the default heading value of `Auth0` displayed in Lock; see following image.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're using the latest version of Lock (Lock 10) you can customize any text shown by Lock through the `languageDictionary` object.

```
var options = {
  languageDictionary: {
    title: "[YOUR_TEXT_HERE]"
  },
};
```

Check the [documentation](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v10/customization#languagedictionary-object-) for additional information on how to use this object.

Answer (score 0):

which value do you want to change? Auth0? If yes, set the value of Auth0 and make it Input(), like:

```
export class HeadComponent {
  @Input() Auth0; 
}
```

in HTML:

```
 <heading-component [Auth0]="custom value"></heading-component>
```